# Renaming Folders ascending

Tags: powershell

I want to automate my backups and Keep always some old versions. The idea was to use Windows Backup on a share and use a PowerShell script to start it.

I'm almost done, but I stuck at the renaming.

Share: `\\Server\SysBackup\WindowsImageBackup`

in that share there are Folders for all PC's I have. So for example I want to Keep the three last backups, it should to the following:

Current Backup: PC1
Old Backups: PC1_1, PC1_2

Now I want to rename them to one higher number

PC1_2 → PC1_3
PC1_1 → PC1_2
PC1 → PC1_1

So the backup now can use the PC1 Folder for the newest backup.

That's what I tried so far:

```
$BackupFolder = Get-ChildItem -Directory ($Target + "\WindowsImageBackup") |
                Where-Object -Property Name -Like $env:computername* |
                Select-Object -Property Name
$CurrentBackups = $BackupFolder.Count

if ($CurrentBackups -ge 1) {
    Push-Location ($Target + "\WindowsImageBackup")

    $i = 0
    $xCurrentArray = $CurrentBackups - 1
    $NewSubVersion = $CurrentBackups

    while ($i -le $CurrentBackups) {
        $NewName = $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray].Name.TrimEnd("_")
        Rename-Item $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray] -NewName 
    }

    Pop-Location
    Clear-Variable $i
}
```

The files are not renamed, and I'm getting the following error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   Rename-Item : Missing an argument for parameter 'NewName'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The error is rather self-explanatory, actually. What don't you understand about it? You're running `Rename-Item source_path -NewName <new_name_missing_here>`. You need to specify the name to which you want to rename the given folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error

```
if ($CurrentBackups -ge 1)
{
    Push-Location ($Target + "\WindowsImageBackup\")

    $i= 0
    $xCurrentArray = $CurrentBackups - 1
    $NewSubVersion = $CurrentBackups

    while ($i -lt $CurrentBackups)
    {

        if ($BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray].Contains("_"))
        {

            $Index = $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray].IndexOf("_")
            $NewName = $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray].Substring(0, $Index)
            Rename-Item $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray] -NewName ($NewName + "_" + $NewSubVersion)
            Clear-Variable Index
            $NewSubVersion--
        }
        else
        {
            $NewName = $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray]
            Rename-Item $BackupFolder[$xCurrentArray] -NewName ($NewName + "_1")
        }
        $i++
        $xCurrentArray--


    }


    Pop-Location
    Clear-Variable i
}
```